# Include last lines of log in Monit alert

Tags: monitoring, alert, monit

I am currently monitoring a Node.JS instance with Monit. It's working great, but I would like to add the last 10 lines of the Node.JS instance's log when something is going wrong. Is this even possible?

Here is how I formatted my mail:

```
set mail-format { 
from: email@email
reply-to: donotreply@email.eu
subject: Alert: Amos instance $HOST -- $EVENT
message: $EVENT for service $SERVICE
        Date:       $DATE
        Action:     $ACTION
        Host:       $HOST
        Description:    $DESCRIPTION

This alert was made possible by Monit & this guy.
```

}